# TDD is applicable all the time?

Tags: tdd

Knowing all the advantages TDD offers.  It is possible to apply strictly and all the time in all kind of projects (large projects)? Or is it nothing more than an exaggeration?

Comment: im just trying to read good differents opinions about the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has to consider both advantages and disadvantages, the main disadvantage being the time cost. You typically need to write 1 line of unit testing for every line of code. TDD makes no sense if your functionality is very likely to change a lot in the future, because you will have to rewrite all tests all the time. For example a case of an early prototype, where you mostly want to just test some idea rather than making a super stable application.

Another case is if you want to **support** the change in your application. Then TDD will give you benefits in the long term. Is it possible to apply strictly? Certainly it is possible, but not easy, as it is typical that business people try to reduce short-term costs and disallow using TDD fully. TDD creates short-term costs (writing the tests) in hope to reduce long-term costs (loosing quality due to sudden bugs or extensive manual tests).

Comment: What is "change a lot"?, all the applications change, and TDD was created precisely for supporting change. if you have good tests you can introduce one change in the application (probably change a few test) and verify that all the other features that you are not changing still works. The systems more difficult to change are the systems without test, people are afraid to change because there is no easy way to verify that the application still works after the changes, the most commons bugs in software are regression bugs.

Comment: Exactly. TDD allows you to be certain that a change does not ruin the system somewhere. But it comes at a price. From business point of view one has to consider what costs will you have if you do TDD and what costs if you don't. I can find extreme cases supporting either option. I admit that TDD is beneficial in long term in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is not possible to use TDD.

For example, when writing classes in c++ to display GUI components, it makes no sense to unit test everything. If using MVP design pattern, models in MVP trio should be unit tested, but not the views.